# How do I resolve a collision's position properly in 2D collision detection?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-physics

My current implementation looks like this:

```
if (shapesCollide) {
    if (velocity.y > 0) entity.position.y = other.position.y - entity.size.y;
    else entity.position.y = other.position.y + other.size.y;

    velocity.y = 0;

    if (velocity.x > 0) entity.position.x = other.position.x - entity.size.x;
    else entity.position.x = other.position.x + other.size.x;

    velocity.x = 0;
}
```

However, this leads to weird handling when movement is happening on both axes - for example, having `entity` moving downward to the left of `object`, and then moving it to collide with `object`, will correctly resolve the horizontal collision, but will break the vertical movement.

I previously simply went

```
if (shapesCollide) {
    position = oldPosition;
    velocity = { 0, 0 };
}
```

But this lead to another multi-axis issue: if I have my `entity` resting atop the `object`, it will be unable to move, as the gravity-induced movement will constantly cancel out *both* velocities. I also tried considering both axes separately, but this lead to issues whenever the collision only occurs when *both* velocities are taken into account.

What is the best solution to resolving collision on two axes?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the entities can be considered to be more or less round and that size is the radius of the entities?

We probably need a little vector math to resolve this. (I don't know the square-root function in c++, so be aware at sqrt.) Try replacing your code inside if(shapesCollide) with this and see how it works for you.

```
float rEntity = sqrt(entity.size.x * entity.size.x + entity.size.y * entity.size.y);
float rOther = sqrt(other.size.x * other.size.x + other.size.y * other.size.y);

float midX = (entity.position.x + other.position.x) / 2.0;
float midY = (entity.position.y + other.position.y) / 2.0;

float dx = entity.position.x - midX;
float dy = entity.position.y - midY;
float D = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

*rEntity* and *rOther* are the radii of the objects, and *midX* and *midY* are their center coordinates. *dx* and *dy* are the distances to the center from the entity.

Then do:

```
entity.position.x = midX + dx * rEntity / D;
entity.position.y = midY + dy * rEntity / D;

other.position.x = midX - dx * rOther / D;
other.position.y = midY - dy * rOther / D;
```

You should probably check that *D* is not 0, and if it is, just set dx = 1, dy = 0, D = 1 or something like that.

You should also still do:

```
velocity.x = 0;
velocity.y = 0;
```

if you want the entities to stop.

For more accurate modelling, you could also try the following:

```
float rEntity = sqrt(entity.size.x * entity.size.x + entity.size.y * entity.size.y);
float rOther = sqrt(other.size.x * other.size.x + other.size.y * other.size.y);

float midX = (entity.position.x * rOther + other.position.x * rEntity) / (rEntity + rOther);
float midY = (entity.position.y * rOther + other.position.y * rEntity) / (rEntity + rOther);

float dxEntity = entity.position.x - midX;
float dyEntity = entity.position.y - midY;
float dEntity = sqrt(dxEntity * dxEntity + dyEntity * dyEntity);

float dxOther = other.position.x - midX;
float dyOther = other.position.y - midY;
float dOther = sqrt(dxOther * dxOther + dyOther * dyOther);

entity.position.x = midX + dxEntity * rEntity / dEntity;
entity.position.y = midY + dyEntity * rEntity / dEntity;

other.position.x = midX + dxOther * rOther / dOther;
other.position.y = midY + dyOther * rOther / dOther;
```

which finds the midpoints when the radii are taken into account. But I won't guarantee that that works. Also, the signs on the last additions are important.

I hope this helps (and works). Let me know if something is unclear.